# Duplicacion de icono en Toolbar

Tags: java, android, programación-móvil

tengo un problema con un proyecto, resulta que tengo en el toolbar un buscador el cual busca dentro de un recyclerView, la busqueda me funciona de maravilla, el problema es que cuando me cambio de un fragment a otro se me duplica el icono de busqueda, esto sucede cada vez que cambio de un fragment a otro. El primer fragment contiene un ViewPager y el carrito es un fragment normal, adjunto imagenes del proyecto, si me pudieran ayudar estaria muy agradecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui hago el cambio de fragment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando vuelvo al fragment que contiene el viewPager se me duplica el icono de busqueda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el codigo donde cargo el toolbar

```
package com.example.ingmanuel.mercaexpress.Fragments.Categories;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ingmanuel.mercaexpress.Adapters.ProductsAdapter;
```

import

com.example.ingmanuel.mercaexpress.Interface.IcomunicaFragmentProduct;

```
 import com.example.ingmanuel.mercaexpress.Models.ProductsModel;
 import com.example.ingmanuel.mercaexpress.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link LacteosFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link LacteosFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class LacteosFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerProducts;
private ArrayList<ProductsModel> productList;
private ProductsAdapter adapter;

Activity activity;
IcomunicaFragmentProduct icomunicaFragmentProduct;




// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public LacteosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment LacteosFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static LacteosFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    LacteosFragment fragment = new LacteosFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lacteos, container, false);

    productList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerProducts = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_milk);
    recyclerProducts.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2));

    llenarLista();

    adapter =  new ProductsAdapter(productList);
    recyclerProducts.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**Desde aqui capturamos el evento onclick**/
    onclick();

    return v;
}

private void onclick() {
    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            icomunicaFragmentProduct.sendProduct(productList.get(recyclerProducts.getChildAdapterPosition(v)));
        }
    });

}

private void llenarLista() {

    productList.add(new ProductsModel(1,1,R.drawable.ahorro, "Arroz Blanquita", "2000", "Arroz Blanquita 500gr", "No", "No"));
    productList.add(new ProductsModel(2,1,R.drawable.ahorro, "Arroz Roa", "1900", "Arroz Roa 500gr", "No", "No"));
    productList.add(new ProductsModel(3,1,R.drawable.ahorro, "Arroz Popular", "1500", "Arroz popular 500gr", "No", "No"));
    productList.add(new ProductsModel(1,1,R.drawable.ahorro, "Arroz Lider", "1600", "Arroz Blanco 400gr", "No", "No"));

}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof Activity){
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        icomunicaFragmentProduct = (IcomunicaFragmentProduct) this.activity;
    }

    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.search:

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Invalida el menu de la actividad antes de setHasOptionsMenu(true); solo tienes que llamar getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: yo tengo el setHasOptionsMenu(true); en el onCreate del fragment, entonces coloco el getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); encima o en donde

Comment: En la línea antes(encima) del setHasOptionsMenu(true);

Comment: Mira que intento colocando la linea getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); encima pero no hace nada, sera que lleva algun otro codigo??

Answer (score 2):

espero y te encuentres muy bien.
Yo tenia el mismo problema, la forma en que logre solucionar el problema fue agregando unas lineas de código en el método llamado **onCreateOptionsMenu**.

Las siguientes dos lineas son las que resolvieron el problema, solo hay que agregarlas al inicio del método, después de la llave de apertura del método y antes del `inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);`

```
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
```

Te quedaría así el código

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar,menu);
```

El código lo debes de agregar en el fragmento o actividad donde se repite el icono.

Saludos.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por tu colaboración, me he matado la cabeza varios días intentando arreglar ese problemas y tu me das la solución, muchas gracias. 

Comment: De nada, me alegra que te haya servido. Saludos